# Positive elements of a $C^*$-algbera form a poset

Tags: functional-analysis, order-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

My knowledge of $C^*$-algebras is very little.

We call an element positive if $a=b^*b$ for some $b$ and make a relation on all positive elements by saying 
$$
b \geqslant a \iff b-a \text{ is  positive}.
$$ 
I can't figure out why this gives us a poset.

Comment: I was more wondering about the fact why this relation is anti-symmetric.

Comment: I did not read carefully and was operating under a different definition of positive than you. My apologies.

Comment: Does the partial order only apply to positive elements are is it meant for the whole algebra?

Comment: I think we can take the relation on all elements (despite my formulation.)

Answer (score 3):

Below is one avenue.

Since $a=b^*b$, we have $a^*=a$. Then $C^*(a)$, the C$^*$-subalgebra generated by $a$, is commutative. In a commutative Banach algebra, we have
$$
\sigma(a)=\{\tau(a):\ \tau \text{ is a character }\}.
$$
So, when $a=b^*b$, $\tau(a)=\tau(b^*)\tau(b)=\overline{\tau(b)}\tau(b)=|\tau(b)|^2\geq0$ for any character $\tau$. Thus, $\sigma(a)\subset[0,\infty)$.

If $a\geq0$ and $a\leq0$, we deduce that $\sigma(a)=\{0\}$. Being selfadjoint, the spectral theorem implies that $a=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Only anti-symmetry seems to be non-trivial here. Let us apply the spectral theorem.

Suppose that $b\leqslant a$ and $a\leqslant b$. Since $a-b$ is positive, $C^*(a-b)$ is commutative and of course $b-a\in C^*(a-b)$. But now you can think of $a-b$ and $b-a$ as continuous functions on $\sigma(a-b)$ which are both positive (non-negative, strictly speaking). Since $a-b = -(b-a)$, necessarily $a-b=0$.

Comment: Why is the generated algebra commutative?

Comment: I think this are the polynomials in $a-b$ which clearly form a commutative sub-algebra.

Comment: Because $a-b$ is positive, so we may use the spectral theorem to conclude that $C^*(a-b) \cong C_0(\sigma(a-b))$

Comment: And why is the spectrum positive according to the above definition?

Comment: Freeze_S, thanks for the downvote. These are very basic things: do you know equivalent conditions for an element to be positive?

Comment: Nope, but I guess my question is yet a bit too advanced for my level of knowledge. I first have to dive into it.